# Java process using more RAM than assigned?

Tags: java, linux, memory, centos, minecraft

Basically I run a minecraft server on a Centos 6.2 16GB system

I boot through rtoolkit to start my server, now I assigned it to use 12GB however it is using muc more than that and I do not know why.
I run this command to run the jar file:

```
java -Xmx30M -Xms30M -XX:MaxPermSize=40M -jar Minecraft_RKit.jar USER:PASS
```

That then runs the process with the command:

```
java -Xms12288M -Xmx12288M -Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal -jar /home/craftbukkit.jar nogui
```

Now if I look at my Webmin module I can see that it is using exactly 18025792 kB of RAM. Way more than I have assigned. This has subsequently lead to the process using so much memory that it just crashes the system.

I might be making a stupid error here, but I would really appreciate if anyone could shed some light on this situation.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few other memory consumers in JVM:

- On 64-bit OS [each thread needs at least a MiB of memory](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#threads_oom). 5 thousand threads (unlikely, but if this is a server) can will fill up the gap between 12 GiB of assigned heap and 17 GiB of used memory
- Native code has its own heap
- PermGen settings aren't mentioned in your second command line

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the maximum heap size, this is often the largest but not ALL the memory usage.

You have thread local stacks (This can add up to GB is you have lots of them), shared libraries code and any memory used by C libraries.

BTW 16 GB is 17,179,000,000 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible explanation (in addition to thread stacks, permgen and native heap) is that the Minecraft server could be using large memory-mapped files, or something like that.